# Remote debugging Win32 VCL application built with custom runtime packages: bpl not found

Tags: delphi, remote-debugging, vcl, bpl, paserver

I wrote a Win32 VCL application in Delphi 11.1 Alexandria, the application uses runtime packages that I also wrote myself. The application runs correctly on my development machine.

I'm now trying to remote debug this application. The remote debugger (paserver) is setup correctly on the second machine (windows 10).

When I try to run the application, the deployment process starts and copies runtime packages from `c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\` and `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl\` but stops with the error:

```
[Error Error] Required local file "MSTools280.bpl" not found. Deployment failed.
```

MSTools is one of the custom built packages. In the build event I copy the bpl to `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl\` so it should be visible to my local machine like the other runtime packages.

Both the packages and the application are compiled with `Debug Information = True` and `Include remote debug symbols = True`

I have tried to build a little test application without the custom packages and the remote debugging works correctly for that application.

What can I do to make this work correctly with my custom packages?